# Use celery with Django-regristration-redux to email users on signup

Tags: django, email, celery, registration

I'm using django-registration-redux for registration and wandering where I can add celery into it so it doesn't block and hold up the page when a user signs up?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok if anyone finds this and needs to do the same I managed to do it by first creating an app 
e.g. "django-celery-reg"

Overode the url to "register/"like so:

```
url(r'^register/$', CeleryRegistrationView.as_view(), name='registration_register'),
```

(Look for RegistrationView in default backends views within dj-reg-redux)

Then in 'views.py' override the registration_profile variable

```
class CeleryRegistrationView(RegistrationView):

    registration_profile = CeleryRegistrationProfile
```

Now in 'models.py' subclass RegistrationProfile, and add the following. Remove the 'request' argument as its unlikely needed and cant be serialized, which is needed by celery. Convert site object to its string(now serializable).

```
class RegistrationProfile(RegistrationProfile):

    objects = CeleryRegistrationManager()

    def celery_send_activation_email(self, site):
       site = site.__str__()
       id=self.id
       celery_task_send_activation_email.delay(id, site)
```

In new model manager above this code, override and change 'create_inactive_user' method

```
    if send_email:
        registration_profile.send_activation_email(site)
```

to

```
    if send_email:
        registration_profile.celery_send_activation_email(site)
```

Now the original bulk of the original 'send_activation_email' method(now called 'celery_task_send_activation_email') goes into 'tasks.py'
Override the 'send_activation_email' making sure to use the '@shared_task' decorator. Remove 'request' argument and throughout the method as it isnt necessary. Change 'self' argument to 'id' because again the object cant be serialized. Grab the registration object with the Id and change 'self.user' throughout the method

```
`@shared_task
```

`def celery_task_send_activation_email(id, site):`

```
   user = RegistrationProfile.objects.get(id=id)
   activation_email_subject = getattr(settings, 
  'ACTIVATION_EMAIL_SUBJECT',

  'registration/activation_email_subject.txt')
   activation_email_body = getattr(settings, 'ACTIVATION_EMAIL_BODY',
                                'registration/activation_email.txt')
   activation_email_html = getattr(settings, 'ACTIVATION_EMAIL_HTML',
                                'registration/activation_email.html')

   ctx_dict = {
       'user': user.id,
       'activation_key': user.activation_key,
       'expiration_days': settings.ACCOUNT_ACTIVATION_DAYS,
   }
   subject = (getattr(settings, 'REGISTRATION_EMAIL_SUBJECT_PREFIX', '') +
           render_to_string(
               activation_email_subject, ctx_dict))
   # Email subject *must not* contain newlines
   subject = ''.join(subject.splitlines())
   from_email = get_from_email(site)
   message_txt = render_to_string(activation_email_body,
                               ctx_dict)

   email_message = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, message_txt,
                                       from_email, [user.user.email])

   if getattr(settings, 'REGISTRATION_EMAIL_HTML', True):
       try:
           message_html = render_to_string(
            activation_email_html, ctx_dict)
       except TemplateDoesNotExist:
          pass
       else:
          email_message.attach_alternative(message_html, 'text/html')
email_message.send()
```